# Wagtail snippets dont migrate

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I started to build startup project using Django and Wagtail, but I have one problem, snippets don't migrate.

```
limbro/
  config/
  website/
```

this is a base project structure.

PS D:\Documents\GitHub\limbro.io> python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
PS D:\Documents\GitHub\limbro.io>

snippets.py file in website

```py
from django.db import models

from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel

@register_snippet
class Footer(models.Model):
    facebook_page = models.URLField(blank=True)
    instagram_page = models.URLField(blank=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('facebook_page'),
        FieldPanel('instagram_page'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Footer"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Footer"
        verbose_name_plural = "Footer"
```

Answer (score 2):

The Django migration framework specifically looks for a module called `models` within your app - if your models are defined in `snippets.py`, it won't find them. One way to fix this is to add an `import` line to `models.py`:

```
from .snippets import Footer
```